# I don't mean that this I mean this this

Tags: typescript

Following code snippet in typescript does not work the way I mean. It should be self-explanatory:

```
declare interface Date {
    toUrlString(): string;
}

Date.prototype.toUrlString = () => {
    return this.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
};

document.write(
    new Date().toUrlString()
    // Error: Object [object Window] has no method 'toISOString'
);
```

Compiled code is:

```
var _this = this;
Date.prototype.toUrlString = function () {
    return _this.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
};
document.write(new Date().toUrlString());
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=>` 'fat arrow' notation invokes lexical scoping rules. Use a traditional function if you don't want that:

```
Date.prototype.toUrlString = function() {
    return this.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
};
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! I should make it a rule for myself to always use function keyword when extending object prototypes.

Comment: With the advent of ES6, it is scary that Typescript decided to re-purpose the lambda (=>) with a different meaning. I feel like Typescript should define a new version of `this` that always refers to the class instead, for example, `_this` or `class` or `my`.

Comment: @JoshG Actually, both Typescript and [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) use the same lexical scoping rules for `this` with fat arrow functions.

Comment: :-D True story. Since posting this bit of ignorance I have definitely learned that. Thanks for clarifying!